# Is there a way for CMake to utilize dependencies generated by `swig -MM`?

Tags: python, c++, cmake, dependencies, swig

SWIG generates wrapper code from your C/C++ in a desired target language (Python, Java, C#, etc) using an interface (.i) file that specifies the input code to be wrapped as described in the [SWIG tutorial](http://swig.org/tutorial.html). CMake can be used to call swig in order to generate target code from the .i interface, as described in the [SWIG documentation](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#Introduction_build_system).

However, using this method CMake only generates a dependency for the interface file itself, but not for the source files it includes. One can [manually add dependencies](http://public.kitware.com/pipermail/cmake/2012-December/053045.html), but SWIG can generate dependencies automatically with the -MM option, and I would like for these to be utilized by CMake.

There was a [commit to CMake](http://public.kitware.com/Bug/view.php?id=4147) that utilized dependencies generated by `swig -MM` but [it was later reverted](http://public.kitware.com/Bug/view.php?id=12307) due to a problem with generated sources that didn't exist at the time of the call to swig. At this time the problem seems to remain unsolved.

So I put the issue to the brilliant StackOverflow community: ***Is there a way with the current CMake to utilize dependencies generated by `swig -MM`*** when the interface file (a) does not include generated code (e.g. config.h), and (b) includes generated code?

Here is a small example that can be used for experimentation ([download it here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ii7zh6pk02u6ona/swig_example.zip?dl=0)).

```
// swig_example.h
int foo(int n);
//*** comment this declaration after compiling once to witness dependency failure ***/
int another_function();
```

```
// swig_example.cpp
#include "swig_example.h"
int another_function() {return -1;}
int foo(int n) 
{
    if (n <= 1) return 1;
    else return another_function();
}
```

```
// swig_example: example.i
%module example
%{
#include "swig_example.h"
%}
%include "swig_example.h"
```

```
# swig_example: CMakeLists.txt
FIND_PACKAGE(SWIG REQUIRED)
INCLUDE(${SWIG_USE_FILE})
FIND_PACKAGE(PythonLibs)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${PYTHON_INCLUDE_PATH})
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
SET(CMAKE_SWIG_FLAGS "")

SET_SOURCE_FILES_PROPERTIES(example.i PROPERTIES CPLUSPLUS ON)

#add manual dependencies (must be called before SWIG_ADD_MODULE)
#SET(SWIG_MODULE_example_EXTRA_DEPS ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/swig_example.h)

SWIG_ADD_MODULE(example python example.i swig_example.cpp)
SWIG_LINK_LIBRARIES(example ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES})
```

Compile it once, then comment the declaration of `another_function` and try to compile again. Because the swig interface is not regenerated an error occurs trying to compile examplePYTHON_wrap.cxx.

```
examplePYTHON_wrap.cxx:3220:17: error: use of undeclared identifier 'another_function'
  result = (int)another_function();
```

Uncomment the *add manual dependencies* line of the CMakeLists.txt and the interface will be properly regenerated. However, I want this to work using dependencies generated from `swig -MM` instead of needing to manually specify dependencies.

```
$ swig -python -MM -c++ ../example.i
../example_wrap.cxx: \
  ../example.i \
  ../swig_example.h \
```

Comment: I think you are searching for this: [CMake: adding automatic handling of dependencies for swig-generated modules](http://www.cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2013-January/053345.html). I don't think that the `SWIG_GET_WRAPPER_DEPENDENCIES()` found its way back into the official branch, but the source code can be found [here](http://www.cmake.org/gitweb?p=cmake.git;a=commitdiff;h=fc045318).

Comment: Do you do the commenting of `swig_example.h` because you get a "file not found" error on your first try? If yes, you can keep the `SET(SWIG_MODULE_example_EXTRA_DEPS ...)` line uncommented by telling CMake that `swig_example.h` file is going to be generated. Add the following after your `SWIG_ADD_MODULE()` call: `set_source_files_properties(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/swig_example.h PROPERTIES GENERATED 1)`

Comment: @Florian those are both useful notes. I already mentioned the reverted commit in my question, which technically handles case a) above. Regarding PROPERTIES GENERATED, this was something I wasn't aware of, and is certainly useful. Is it possible to modify the now defunct SWIG_GET_WRAPPER_DEPENDENCIES to itself depend on CMake generated inputs?

Comment: When I look at the discussion on [0012307: regression in 2.8.5 rc2: UseSWIG.cmake broken](http://public.kitware.com/Bug/view.php?id=12307) I don't believe that `SWIG_GET_WRAPPER_DEPENDENCIES()` was actually broken it just introduced a new restriction: "this simply require all headers for swig module to be present" before calling `SWIG_ADD_MODULE()`. Can you give the `SWIG_GET_WRAPPER_DEPENDENCIES()` code a try? According to [this](http://public.kitware.com/Bug/view.php?id=4147) with the patch you just call `SWIG_ADD_MODULE()` and it calls `SWIG_GET_WRAPPER_DEPENDENCIES()` for you.

Comment: And - supplementing my last comment and in contradiction to my comment 2 days ago - it will _not_ be a good idea to set all files in `SWIG_MODULE_example_EXTRA_DEPS` to `GENERATED`. Because it's a feature that you get an "file not found" error message if a dependency is missing.

Comment: I suggested a fix at [0004147: MODULES UseSWIG: Use swig to compute dependencies](http://public.kitware.com/Bug/view.php?id=4147). The CMake team is searching someone interested in working on the feature. Would you like to take the ticket and do the testing?

Comment: Hmm, the way I usually handle dependencies is to let the swig wrapper depend through linking to a static library. If I change any headers of the dependent library, SWIG is regenerating the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Turning my comments into an answer*

I don't think - if you want to do this automatically and e.g. want to utilize `swig -MM` - that this can be done without changing the [`UseSWIG.cmake`](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/commits/master/Modules/UseSWIG.cmake) code.

When I look at why the previous attempt you have linked was reverted - namely the discussion of on ["0012307: regression in 2.8.5 rc2: UseSWIG.cmake broken"](http://public.kitware.com/Bug/view.php?id=12307) - I don't believe that `SWIG_GET_WRAPPER_DEPENDENCIES()` was actually broken it just introduced a new restriction: "this simply require all headers for swig module to be present" before calling `SWIG_ADD_MODULE()`.

So I suggested to add the `-ignoremissing` SWIG option, but this would need further testing.

---

#### Update (April 2017)

With CMake version 3.8.0 there came a fix ["Automatically scan dependencies of SWIG files for Makefile generators"](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/merge_requests/354) that works for [`makefile` generators](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generators.7.html#makefile-generators).

---

#### Reference

The general discussion of how to fix this (including my suggestion) is discussed at ["Issue #4147: [MODULES][UseSWIG] Use swig to compute dependencies"](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/4147). The ticket is still open (was reopened), so please feel free to add your support, suggestions or test results there.