# cmake + swig + dependicies

Tags: c++, cmake, swig

Today I tried to use combination of "cmake + swig" to generate bindings for my code. Basically it works:

```
set(SWIG_EXECUTABLE "/usr/bin/swig")
find_package(SWIG REQUIRED)
include(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/UseSWIG.cmake)

set(CMAKE_SWIG_FLAGS -package example)
set(CMAKE_SWIG_OUTDIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/example")
set_source_files_properties(native.i PROPERTIES CPLUSPLUS ON)
SWIG_ADD_MODULE(core Java native.i lib.cpp)
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
```

with such native.i:

```
%module native
%include "lib.hpp"
%{
#include "lib.hpp"
  %}
```

But if I change `lib.hpp` build system `cmake build` not call swig to regenerate code. So I have to `touch native.i` to get it works, this is very annoying.

I found `-M` option of `swig` to generate dependencies,
Is any idea how use it to fix `UseSWIG.cmake`?

`UseSWIG.cmake` just uses `add_custom_command` for generation,
so I need somehow `add_custom_command` depend on dynamic set of files,
not static?

Comment: Did you try to add lib.hpp to SWIG_ADD_MODULE: `SWIG_ADD_MODULE(core Java native.i lib.cpp lib.hpp)`?

Comment: @wasthishelpful Yes, and as expected this do not help.

Comment: I think this is basically a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/q/31007635/168175 perhaps?

Comment: @Flexo you are right.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know anything better than the patch that got reverted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that I have found a solution to your request.

I am currently using a solution, where all relevant dependencies are added such that `SWIG` re-generates the interface, whenever any of the headers parsed are modified.

The idea is to make a custom target, which touch a dummy file in addition to deleting the generated interface file. I have put the solution below for a project named `fnm` with a wrapper `swig_fnm`.

```
# Method to make swig_fnm.i depend on input headers
execute_process(COMMAND swig -M -python -c++  -I${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/.. -I${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/.. swig_fnm.i
  WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
  OUTPUT_VARIABLE swig_deps
  INPUT_FILE swig_fnm.i)
# Match all lines except the first one until " \"
string(REGEX MATCHALL "\n  [^ ]+" temp ${swig_deps})

# Valid dependency extensions
set(valid_ext .h .hpp)

# Dependency list
set(swig_deps_actual)
foreach(t ${temp})
  string(STRIP "${t}" t)

  # Add to dependency list
  if (EXISTS "${t}")
    set(filter)
    get_filename_component(filter "${t}" EXT)
    if (";${valid_ext};" MATCHES ";${filter};")
      set(swig_deps_actual ${swig_deps_actual} "${t}")
    endif()
  endif()
endforeach()

# This makes configure run again, but does not regenerate the SWIG interface.
set_property(DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} APPEND PROPERTY CMAKE_CONFIGURE_DEPENDS ${swig_deps_actual})

# All headers except for the single .i file are ignored
swig_add_module(swig_fnm python swig_fnm.i ${swig_fnm_HEADERS} ${swig_deps_actual})

# Removes generated file (if any of the dependent files are changed)
add_custom_command(
  OUTPUT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/swig.stamp
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E remove ${swig_generated_file_fullname}
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E touch ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/swig.stamp
  DEPENDS ${swig_deps_actual} # The dependent files
  COMMENT "Removing old SWIG generated file" VERBATIM)

# Custom target for establishing dependency
add_custom_target(
  swigtrick
  DEPENDS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/swig.stamp)

# Dependency
add_dependencies(_swig_fnm swigtrick)
```

Answer (score 2):

During configuration you can run swig with the -M flag to generate the dependencies. You can then parse the output of that and pass it as DEPDENDS to add_custom_command.

The output looks like:

```
test_wrap.c: \
  .../swig.swg \
  ... \
  test.i \
  test.h
```

This can be generated with execute_command and needs further processing:

```
execute_process(COMMAND swig -M <SWIG_ARGUMENTs> OUTPUT_VARIABLES swig_deps)

# Match all lines except the first one until " \"
string(REGEX MATCHALL "\n  [^ ]+" temp ${swig_deps})
set(swig_deps)
foreach(t ${temp})
    string(STRIP "${t}" t)
    set(swig_deps ${swig_deps} "${t}")
endforeach()

...

add_custom_command(... DEPENDS ${swig_deps})
```

This makes swig depend on all headers that are included in the .i files. If one of the .i or the header files is edited in a way that adds new dependencies you need to reconfigure so cmake knows about it. This can happen automatically if you add CMAKE_CONFIGURE_DEPENDS.

```
set_property(DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} APPEND PROPERTY CMAKE_CONFIGURE_DEPENDS ${swig_deps} test.i)
```

Comment: Although I think this is about as close as it gets right now what happens if the .i file itself includes a header file that is autogenerated by another part of the build process? (I think siwg -M bails and the configure step fails as a result?)

Comment: That is true. A workaround would be to have a wrapper header that includes the generated file instead and then include that in the .i. The generated would then of course needed to be added to the dependencies of the swig command manually.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, looking in the source code for [UseSWIG.cmake](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/UseSWIG.cmake), the [custom commands](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/UseSWIG.cmake#L195) are built on the .i files and miss dependency to [other sources](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/UseSWIG.cmake#L234). What you can do is add [extra dependencies](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/UseSWIG.cmake#L210) to the custom commands:

```
set(SWIG_MODULE_core_EXTRA_DEPS lib.hpp)
SWIG_ADD_MODULE(core Java native.i lib.cpp)
```

Alternatively, you can modify UseSWIG.cmake to automatically add the dependencies:

```
macro(SWIG_ADD_SOURCE_TO_MODULE name outfiles infile other_sources)
    # ...
    add_custom_command(
        # ...
        DEPENDS ${SWIG_MODULE_${name}_EXTRA_DEPS} ${other_sources}
        # ...
    )
endmacro()

# ...

foreach(it ${swig_dot_i_sources})
    SWIG_ADD_SOURCE_TO_MODULE(${name} swig_generated_source ${it} ${swig_other_sources})
    set(swig_generated_sources ${swig_generated_sources} "${swig_generated_source}")
endforeach()
```

Which leads to my initial comment:

```
SWIG_ADD_MODULE(core Java native.i lib.cpp lib.hpp)
```

Comment: Actually I want to automatically generate this dependicies, not add "extra" dependencies each time by hands.

Comment: No, this is too huge dependencies. With your solution I get regeneration of `native.i` on any changes in my code base. I mean `swig -M` generate list of dependencies, and this list I want to pass to `add_custom_command`, the problem that I need update dependicies list every time when `native.i` changed. So it is like `_EXTRA_DEPS`, but dynamic, not static.